# Finding an optimal matrix with a specific sparsity pattern

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I am searching for an $m \times n$ matrix that has the following sparsity pattern

\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_4 & a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8 & a_9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
a_i & a_{i+1} & a_{i+2} & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} & a_n
\end{bmatrix}

The number of zeros on each row can be known ahead of time, and are decreasing until the final row which is all non-zero. In general, $n$ is much larger than $m$ (it's a wide/fat matrix).

Do these types of matrices have names? Do they live in some set in which I can constrain my optimization problem? If not, how can I *encode* this structure within an optimization problem?

I think that the fact that this matrix has so many zeros, and that the *number* of the zeros on each row are *known in advance* should make the problem easier.

EDIT: To clarify, a matrix of this structure is my optimization variable.

Comment: Block-lower triangular? (Notice that high-performance LP solvers will exploit sparsity in the technological coefficient matrix $A$).

Comment: If you put the columns in reversed order, the matrix is in row echelon form. Your question is not clear as to how this matrix appears in your optimization problem; is it a variable or a coefficient matrix?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen can you explain what you mean by "technological coefficient"?

Comment: @LinAlg thanks for you response, and sorry I wasn't clear - I edited the question

Comment: And how does this matrix occur in the optimization problem?

Comment: It is something like $\underset{M}{min} \;\; M\cdot\vec{v}$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo sorry Im not understanding - can't it be something $\underset{M}{\min} \;\; \textbf{Tr}(M) - \log\det M - \lvert\lvert X\rvert\rvert_F$

Comment: I edited the above - Frobenius for example? I got this problem from a textbook, though it doesnt mention the unique structure of $M$ in that textbook - that comes from my personal research

Comment: Why not just include $(m - 1) n$ equality constraints of the form $x_{ij} = 0$?

Comment: Is that how it is best handled? thats what I was wondering - if this is a special matrix with a unique structure, or if I just have to include those constraints.

Comment: The number of zeros are combinatorial, related to a weak integer composition

Comment: I would just use $x_{ij} = 0$. Write a script that generates the data of the problem. Then let a solver handle it.

Comment: @LinAlg It is a coefficient matrix over some space of basis functions - but what I am trying to find are the coefficients over that space